# Updated 12.10 and now get flashing purple screen when booting

Tags: 12.04, 12.10

I'm brand new to Ubuntu (and Linux in general) and have set up 12.10 to dual boot (along with Win7).  Everything was going OK, but when I installed the updates and rebooted, I found that, after choosing to boot into Ubuntu, I got a flashing purple screen with no login.  I was able to reboot again and got into Ubuntu by choosing the advanced option, with boot into safe mode.

When I checked to see what was going on with the display in the settings menu, my monitor now comes up as a laptop monitor, whereas it was previously identified as a 19" Dell monitor before the update.

Keeping in mind that I'm brand new to Ubuntu and the world of Linux, what is likely to be the problem and what can I do about it?

#### Update (21:15 GMT, 2/16/13)

I've gone ahead and reinstalled 12.04, but the problems persist.  I can get everything working OK if I open Ubuntu using recovery mode, otherwise I get the flashing purple screen.  I have, however, gotten the monitor to be detected as  a Dell 19" rather than a laptop screen.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you have an ATI graphics card? I see this with my wife's AMD C-60 based system.  It is intermittent, most times on boot it works fine, but other times it just boots to a blank purple screen. A reboot normally fixes it.  I'm curious if you're having the same issue.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You seem to be using two separate accounts to work on the same question, which I am guessing is not what you intend. This is why your edits have to go through the review queue rather than being immediately applied. Please use the contact us link at the bottom of this page to ask for your unregistered account and your new registered account to be merged. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using 12.04 LTS? That might be your best option, since you are new to Linux. LTS (Long Term Support) versions are the most stable. You won't lose any important features by switching to 12.04.

Have you booted again?

Comment: Hi.  I've tried rebooting a bunch of times and the problem persists.  I'm also leaning to the 12.04 way of doing things - but is there any way I can do this without completely reinstalling everything?  And if so, how?